# import module in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I cloned a git project which has a folder called NOTEBOOKS and another folder called LOADER.
In the LOADER folder, there is a data_loading.py.
In the NOTEBOOKS folder there is a 01_analysis.ipynb, when I open this notebook using jupyter notebook and I want to run first cell:

```
from LOADER import data_loading
```

I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'LOADER'
```

I am sure the code is correct but I need to tell Jupyter where the LOADER is. Is there anything which I need to add to the Jupyter to know where to fidn LOADER?

Answer (score 3):

This is not related to jupyter notebook but python itself. A solution is to create a new module for `data_loading.py` and then install it globally thus allowing you to import it. An alternative will be to add `LOADER` to your path  using

```
import sys  
sys.path.insert(0, 'path to LOADER')
```

and then import `data_loading`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is an install.sh as well in the project folder. Should I run it manually then? It installs imodules globally as you mentioned